# (WinForms) ListView shows tooltips behind its own form when form is topmost

Tags: listview, tooltip, topmost

I have a Form with just a ListView in it. The ListView is set to show tooltips for subitems (in Details view). The tool tip shows fine if the form is not top most. When I set the Form's TopMost to true, the tool tip appears "behind" the window.

Is there any other property/combination of properties that need to be set in order to get the tool tip to show as usual, over the form?

Answer (score 0):

That appears to be either a) by design or b) a bug (depending upon who you believe and what you read about this issue).

Since ToolTips are essentially TopMost windows and your Form is a TopMost window, there is a bit of contention at the O/S level as to what to *really* show as TopMost.

See here: http://www.itags.org/dotnet/169331/

Comment: Yes, that's what I figured. I'm leaning towards b).
I guess this forces developers who want to work-around this to either user third-party controls or dive into the internals of the ListView.